# Add a class to list at variable position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable set that represents an item in the list.

I also have the list:

```
<ul>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I need to do is to add a css class to the list thats in the position of the variable value.

For example:

```
If myVariable = '1' then list will look like this:

<ul>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#" class="myclass">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
</ul>

If myVariable = '3' then list will look like this:

<ul>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#" class="myclass">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li class="mylist"><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

and so on.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("li.mylist").eq(position -1).find("a").addClass("myClass")
```

Comment: This adds the class to the element after the selected position (off by 1 mistake). It should be `position - 1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `eq` method in jQuery for selecting element by index:

```
const myVariable = 3;
$('.mylist').eq(myVariable - 1).find('a').addClass('myClass');
```

Mind that `eq` assumes that your indices are 0-based (which means the first one is 0 and not 1). That's why it's `myVariable - 1`.

Comment: The node list is zero based, so `.eq(num - 1)`

Comment: it could, but the OP's is not.

Answer (score 2):

```
var value = 3;
$('ul li.mylist a').filter(function () {

    return $(this).text() === 'Item ' + value;

}).addClass('myclass');
```

Comment: My first thought was "how silly" but then I realized there's a small chance of this being the right answer :D

Comment: @Miszy - If the value can occur more than once, this is the preferred way to go, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, the question's just not clear whether it's about item's index or content.